# Tableau - Combining two types of dimension values

Tags: tableau-api

On my Tableau sheet, I am measuring the hours of music played (Columns) in different rooms in the house (Rows).

The rooms in the house are divided into bedroom, living room, kitchen, patio, and pool.

I want to combine the hours of music played for outdoor areas (patio and pool) vs indoor areas (bedroom, living room, and kitchen). Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: please show your sample data and current chart

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by grouping, see the following link:
http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/sortgroup_groups_creating.html

Alternatively, use a CASE statement to define a custom definition of your inside and outside areas. For example:

`If Contains([YOUR FIELD],"bedroom")  then "Indoors"
ElseIf Contains([YOUR FIELD],"living room")  then "Indoors"
ElseIf Contains([YOUR FIELD],"kitchen")  then "Indoors"
else "Outdoors"  end`

You can then filter on this field, of view your measures splitting by indoor and outdoor.